# Angular retry http request on a specific successful response (not error)

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, angular-http, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs-observables

I know we can retry a failed HTTP API request through `retry` or `retryWhen` pipe mehtods from rxjs. I want to do something similar on a successful API call, based on a particular condition in the response received.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use the `repeat` operator from RxJs for the successful request because the `repeat` operator resubscribes when it receives `onComplete()` but not by error. Whereas, `retry` operator resubscribes when it receives `onError()`

Please see this [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s2uk3q?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example where a successful request is repeated twice. You can open the console and see the response repeated multiple times.

Comment: Thanks @alicelebi. The `repeat` operator works. My requirement is to repeat the request only till the response received doesn't meet a certain condition. So, the `repeatWhen` operator works for me. I [forked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sa12xr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) your stackblitz example to further add what I wanted. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the completed stage of the observable, so after subscription, you will have: next, error and **completed**. If that condition is coming from the api, like this you will have access to the value and inside the **complete** code block you can do the repetition.